# Need to create a trigger

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, triggers

```
select id, status, name , status_change_dt from account;
```

whenever status changes to any other status status_change_dt should be updated to sysdate

```
create or replace
  TRIGGER ADD_DT 
  after UPDATE of status ON account 
  for each row
  BEGIN 
  :new.status_change_dt := sysdate ;
  END;
```

I am getting error in creating this trigger. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 4):

You can't change the new value after the update.

Even error is pretty clear on this:

> ORA-04084: cannot change NEW values for this trigger type

Use `BEFORE` instead of `AFTER`.

Try this:

```
create or replace
  TRIGGER ADD_DT 
  before UPDATE of status ON account 
  for each row
  BEGIN 
  :new.status_change_dt := sysdate ;
  END;
```

#### EDIT:

If you have another table

```
account_dtl (ref_id references account(id), status_2);
```

And account table has one more column to keep track of status_2 changes, use this:

```
create or replace
  TRIGGER ADD_DT_Status_2 
  before UPDATE of status_2 ON account_dtl
  for each row
  BEGIN 
    update account
    set status2_change_dt := sysdate
    where id = :new.ref_id;
  END;
```

Although it would make more sense to keep track of status_2 changes in its own table i.e. account_dtl

Comment: @Ankush Please see the EDIT